# Programmatically style actionbar menus without using styles.xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, actionbarsherlock, submenu

To start, I know how to use styles.xml and themes.xml to set the style of the actionbar's menu.  Also, I am using ActionbarSherlock and a submenu popup is shown after selecting an item from the actionbar - yes, a submenu because I want icons to show to the left of the text. I can set a simple background drawable for the submenu background but I can't set a colorized, tiled, drawable since it must first be created programatically.  Also, the submenu won't wrap the width of its children and so there is a lot of space sometimes even though all text have similar lengths.

Is it possible to do this using XML?. If not, is it possible to do programatically?